# Author Tracking With Google Analytics on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I'm having a little trouble with getting author tracking set up on my google analytics. This is my code

```
        <script> 
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-XX', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview', {
      'dimension1': '<?=$author?>'
    });

    </script>
```

Now, when I look at the data in my Google Analytics page, I see the author name as "" and not the actual authors

Comment: that's probably because you are sending the string <?=$author?>   really I am surprised I would have expected you to see <?=$author?> in the dimension unless its because its not html encoded.  Interesting.

Comment: @DaImTo Actually that's valid php (for the moment, ASP-style tags will be removed in the near future, but at least with PHP 5.5 they still work). It simply seems that the variable is not set.

Comment: @EikePierstorff nice I always test by being able to see the actual data in the JavaScript.   wouldn't have thought that php could run after the JavaScript was created.  problem must be then that $author isn't set.

Comment: I thought the string was supposed to automatically extract "author name". Got it off https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

Comment: @Nosaaaa There is your problem then. You need to set the value for the string yourself. Here is a post on the SE wordpress site that explains how to get the author name: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65548/how-to-get-author-id-outside-the-loop

Answer (score 0):

## The loop

Are you sure you set it up in the wordpress loop? It really depends, where the variable is setted. If you have this at the beginning oif HTML page, the variable do not have to be available in this time.

#### Shorthand syntax

It seems to be correct shorthand `<?=$author?>`. But try full syntax `<?php echo $author; ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
<?php if (is_single()) :
    $post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id ) ?>
ga('set', 'dimension1', '<?php echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $post_author_id); ?>' );
<?php endif ?>
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure to augment the code in your answer with an explanation of _why_ it should.